# Visual Studio 2022 Profiler not properly expanding stack traces

Tags: profiling, visual-studio-2022

I am migrating a Visual Studio C++ project from VS 2017 to 2022. Everything went fine, until I tried to use the Performance Profiler. It hit a frustrating issue where it's collapsing pretty obvious call graphs into single report lines, despite all attempts to fix. This worked fine with 2017.

For example there is this call:

[image]

This is a thin wrapper around another call that does the "real work", and you can see this in the profiling results:

[image]

But that inner Read() call does not show up in the profile, nor any of the stuff it calls.

I have "Enable Just My Code" turned off. This code is actually "my code", it's linked through a DLL. Debug information is turned on in the DLL build (/Zi) and link.

How can I get VS 2022 to expand stack traces properly? Again this all works flawlessly in VS 2017.

Comment: You should probably submit a repro of this directly to Microsoft.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I was going to do that but, given my inexperience with VS 2022, decided asking here first might lead to a faster resolution.